# Transforming a series of tuples into a series of the nth element of each tuple

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tuples, apply, series

Is there a clean way to transform a `Series` of tuples into another `Series` consisting of first (or nth) element in each tuple? For example,

```
ser = pd.Series([ (0,1,2), (3,4,5) ])
```

Should be transform into a series consisting of 0 and 3:

```
0  0
1  3
```

(where the 0,1 is the index). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor:

```
In [90]: ser.str[0]
Out[90]:
0    0
1    3
dtype: int64
```

which is AFAIK a short form of vectorized [Series.str.get(N)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get.html#pandas.Series.str.get) method:

```
In [92]: ser.str.get(0)
Out[92]:
0    0
1    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Beautiful, can you please comment on why this works? I am asking because I was surprised to see that you invoked `.str`, as it typically pertains to strings, whereas here we have a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) to apply an arbitrary function to your Series. The [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=operator.itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) will return a function that accesses whichever member you want:

```
get0 = operator.itemgetter(0)
my0 = myseries.apply(get0)
```